# Not able to find go_router's official documentation

Tags: flutter-go-router

I was not able to find flutter go_router's official documentation. Their official link was gorouter.dev but now it is redirecting to https://pub.dev/packages/go_router. Any other recourses for go_router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was missing it as well, was able to find a mirror here: https://docs.page/bizz84/go_router_archived

Will also point to the respective github issue for this question: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112159